# Polymer 1.0 How to get the id of the clicked paper button?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have a set of paper buttons like below:

```html
<div><paper-button  id="100" on-tap="addQuantity">100ML</paper-button><paper-button toggles id="200" on-click="addQuantity">200ML</paper-button><paper-button toggles id="300" on-click="addQuantity">300ML</paper-button></div>
```

And i want to know the id of each button when clicked. I tried like this in Javascript function. It does not work

```html
addQuantity:function(e)
  {
   console.log(e.target.id);
   
  }
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
addQuantity: function (e) {
    var button = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget;
    console.log(button.id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the clicked element id:

```
addQuantity:function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    var id = target.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `e.srcElement.id` instead.

Comment: it gives me blank value. console does not print anything.

Comment: when I had something similar, I had to add the id to the icon inside the button div for it to work.